# Can we use AWS Amplify DataStore to upload files to AWS S3 in react native expo project?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo

Currently using the **AWS Amplify DataStore** to build an offline enabled application using react native and expo, but my data is a bit complex because it includes primitive data types(like string, number, array), also includes some files(pdf, images, doc). I want the feature to save document in offline mode, the application data is working in offline mode as per design. When the user comes back online , the documents will be uploaded to S3, offline should save it to the application (upload docs feature)

Read AWS documents, the AWS Mobile SDK for android mentioned that we can allow the offline feature including documents for Android (Storage - Using GraphQL API - Android - AWS Amplify Docs:https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/storage/graphql-api/q/platform/android/#client-code). BUT CANNOT FIND THIS FEATURE FOR JAVASCRIPT

If anyone can help -PLEASE I AM STUCK! :-)

Thank you so much.